# Excluding elements from the queryset on a inlineformset

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, formset

So lets say I have these models:

```
class Club(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    members = models.ManyToMany(User)
    

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, models.CASCADE)
```

So  what I need is to get all the club's events, but on an inlineformset, or any kind of formset.

I could create a working formset with this:

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory

def my_view(request):
    ...
    CustomFormset = inlineformset_factory(Club, Event, fields=('name', 'date'))
    actual_formset = CustomFormset(instance=Club.objects.get(pk=1)
    ...
```

Now that works but I get every single event related to the club, but what I actually need to get elements that fit some parameters, for example I want only elements with date greater than today.

I haven't found a way to accomplish this and would appreciate any guidance.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can use [exclude()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) with your `queryset` to exclude objects with a given condition.

It can be applied globally on objects as it was shown in the docs - which I believe it's your case- or it can be combined with any other `queryset` methods like `filter()`

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way is to create a ModelForm and to override validation in it. Then use it to call the formset.

```
#forms.py
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Event
    fields = ['name', 'date',]

    def clean_date(self):
        date = self.cleaned_data.get('date')
        if date < timezone.today():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Please enter a date greater than today')
        return date
```

Then:

```
CustomFormset = inlineformset_factory(Club, Event, form=EventForm)
```

> The **clean_fieldname()** method is called on a form subclass – where  is replaced with the name of the form field attribute. This method does any cleaning that is specific to that particular attribute, unrelated to the type of field that it is. This method is not passed any parameters. You will need to look up the value of the field in self.cleaned_data and remember that it will be a Python object at this point, not the original string submitted in the form (it will be in cleaned_data because the general field clean() method, above, has already cleaned the data once).

[Overriding the clean() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method)

[Form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding the argument queryset when creating the actual_formset object and I think it works the way you want it to. There you can filter for objects within the main instance with a certain date or whatever. Hope this helps.

```
actual_formset = CustomFormset(
    instance=Club.objects.get(pk=1),
    queryset=Event.objects.filter(date__gte = timezone.today())
)
```